# Change Custom Icon Font in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, xcode7

I am using a custom Icon font in XCode 7.3 and had the font updated to include new icons.

The font is defined in the info plist

Problem is XCode 7.3 does not see the new icons for this project but can see them for new projects. I get just |?| for the new icons. I can test it out by pasting the icon from font book onto a storyboard label

I have tried cleaning the derived data and this did not help.

I have deleted and re-added the font from the project, no change

Comment: What's happening when you run your app? Do you still have the |?| ? Or are you speaking specially of the appearance of your app in the IB?

Comment: I got the ? I have solved this now

Answer (score 0):

I did two things and am not sure which one solved it

I cleaned the build folder

```
(command + alt + shift + k)
```

I cleaned the X Code Module Cache

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

Everything is fine now.